# How to run the bash when we trigger docker run command without -it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM centos
RUN mkdir work
RUN yum install -y python3 java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tar git wget zip
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install pynt
WORKDIR ./work
CMD ["bash"]
```

where i am installing some basic dependencies.
Now when I run

`docker run imagename`

it does nothing but when I run

`docker run -it imageName`

I lands into the bash shell. But I want to get into the bash shell as soon as I trigger the run command without any extra parameters.

I am using this docker container in AWS codebuild and there I can't specify any parameters like -it but I want to execute my code in the docker container itself.
Is it possible to modify CMD/ENTRYPOINT in such a way that when running the docker image I land right inside the container?

Comment: Generally you'd actually install your code in the `Dockerfile`, and set the `CMD` to run it.  In automated cloud build environments there's a general expectation that the build will run end-to-end without any user intervention; I don't think you'd have any opportunity to interact with a container shell in a CodeBuild build.

Comment: If you look at the images provided by aws, they are using dockerd-entrypoint.sh to keep the container running and then we run our commands using build-spec....So if you can explain how dockerd works...Here is the link to aws's image..https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/al2/x86_64/standard/1.0/dockerd-entrypoint.sh

Comment: That is an unusual Docker image and does many things I'd actively recommend against.  (The Dockerfile is literally 10-20x longer than a typical application Dockerfile, and the image will be correspondingly huge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot login to the docker container directly.
If you want to run any specific commands when the container start in detach mode than either you can give it in CMD and ENTRYPOINT command of the Dockerfile.

If you want to get into the shell directly, you can run

`docker -it run imageName`

or

`docker run imageName bash -c "ls -ltr;pwd"`

and it will return the output.
If you have triggered the run command without -it param then you can get into the container using:

`docker exec -it imageName`

and you will land up into the shell.

Now, if you are using AWS codebuild custom images and concerned about how the commands can be submitted to the container than you have to put your commands into the build_spec.yaml file and put your commands either in pre_build, build or post_build parameter and those commands will be submitted to the docker container.

-build_spec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip install boto3 #or any prebuild configuration

  build:
    commands:
      - spark-submit job.py
  post_build:
    commands:
      - rm -rf /tmp/*
```

More about build_spec [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your container, it will not even build due to missing `pip`. So I modified it a bit so that it at least builds:

```
FROM centos
RUN mkdir glue
RUN yum install -y python3 java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tar git wget zip python3-pip
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install boto3
RUN pip3 install pynt
WORKDIR ./glue
```

Build it using, e.g.:

```
docker build . -t glue
```

Then you can run command in it using for example the following syntax:

```
docker run --rm  glue bash -c "mkdir a; ls -a; pwd"
```

I use `--rm` as I don't want to keep the container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Marcin...I am trying to use this container inside a codebuild....now there I can't specify my command to run the container so I want something like dockerd-entrypoint...I don't know now how it works but that is probably what I am looking out for now

Comment: Why you wouldn't be able to use it in codebuild? You are creating the container for custom CB environment? Otherwise use it in `buildspec.yml` as anyother command.

Comment: I will try using in buildspec...Look at this if you can simplify it for me....this is used by amazon for creating their containers and keep them running...https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/al2/x86_64/standard/1.0/dockerd-entrypoint.sh

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could edit your question and provide more details. The link you provided is for amazon managed build envorionments. You want to create your own build environment instead of using what aws offers?

Comment: Yes I am trying to provide my custom build environment through docker image for running some specific jobs so that require me get into the shell....

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get to shell even with your own environment. CodeBuild just executes the commands from `buildspec.yml`. The commands are executed against AWS own images, or your custom ones.

Comment: I am trying to execute through buildspec....if succeeds i'll update here....thanks

Comment: Thanks! it worked by just giving commands through build_spec file in pre_build and build commands.

Comment: Glad to hear. If so acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.